# Ajax Cart - Out of stock

Tags: error, controllers, ajax, out-of-stock

I have **ajax cart** from **porto theme**.
But when I am add more product than stock, the ajax cart crash (wheel is just rotating) and I got no message
How to fix this issue?
[image]

Comment: can't just completely answer this because I don't have clear information on this, but you can start with inspecting in you browser, and see the response in Network tab. And backtrack to your controller.